# adding a php where clause to a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, where-clause

Using PHP

I'm trying to build a schedule of events (limited to the next 5) and I don't want to include any events that have past. In other words, the day after the event it should fall off the schedule.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `lfc_events`
WHERE event_year >= $year
AND event_month >= $month
LIMIT 0, 5
```

I'm using a foreach loop to build the table:

```
foreach ($evts as $evt) {
        $evtnum = substr($evt->event_name, -2);    // returns the number of the event (ex: LFC 21 -- the 21 is returned)
            if ($evt->event_fightcard == "") {
                $evtlink = 'LFC ' . $evtnum;
            }
            else {
                $evtlink = '<a href="' . $evt->event_fightcard . '">LFC ' . $evtnum . '</a>';
            }

        $res.='
            <tr>
                <td>' . $evt->event_month . '/' . $evt->event_day . '/' . $evt->event_year . '</td>
                <td>' . $evtlink . '</td>
                <td>' . $evt->event_city . ',' . $evt->event_state . '</td>
            </tr>';
}
```

Is it possible to add a where clause to the foreach loop?

For illustration purposes, this is my goal:

```
foreach ($evts as $evt where $evt->event_day >= $today) {
     // code...
}
```

Comment: `Is it possible to add a where clause to the foreach loop?` no

Comment: Build the `WHERE` into your SQL query and select only records >= today.

Comment: Wouldn't this exclude events that happen prior to that day but in future months? For example if today is the 15th, and the next event happens on the 7th of the next month, that event would be excluded. I should point out I am storing the date of the events in separate columns (month, day and year).